# Dynamic element JavaScript at click

Tags: javascript

Newbie in JavaScript, having done (without results) research on what I wanted, I then need help to have a script which allows to make an effect on a div when click on it.

```
<div id="Tests">
<div id="Test"> test 1</div>
<div id="Test> test 2</div>
</div>
```

When you click "Test 1" for example, must it become blue (example), and then if I click on "Test 2", the div "Test 1" returns to normal, the div "Test 2" sees with the blue background.

[Example GIF](https://gyazo.com/60f8dd4f08a57ea4d3507a85145f3449)

EDIT: Thanks for your help, my problem is resolved !

Comment: `id` should be unique

Comment: The id should be unique per page.

Comment: Pranav C Balan & ionutvmi, oops, I was wrong, I made the mistake in the text editor, excuse me, otherwise on my original code I "1" then "2" :/

Comment: Yes Alexandru Severin

Comment: My problem is resolved !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work  !

```js
var el = document.getElementById('group');
el.onclick = function(evt){
  var ex = document.getElementsByClassName('selected')[0];
  ex.className = ex.className.replace('selected' , '');
  evt.target.className = this.className + ' selected '; 
  }
```

```css
div {
  border : solid 1px #CCC;
  padding : 3px;
  margin : 3px;
  }
.selected {
  border : solid 3px steelblue;
  padding : 2px;
 }
```

```html
<div id='group'>
<div class='selected'>Line 1</div>
<div class=''>Line 2</div>
<div class=''>Line 3</div>
<div class=''>Line 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, my problem is resolved !

Comment: great . You're welcome !

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small fiddle showing what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/gpv377h2/

HTML:

```
<div id="test1">test 1</div>

<div id="test2">test 2</div>
```

JS:

```
var test1 = document.getElementById('test1');
test1.addEventListener('click',
    function () {
        this.style.background = 'blue';
    }
);

var test2 = document.getElementById('test2');
test2.addEventListener('click',
    function () {
        this.style.background = 'blue';
        test1.style.background = '';
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, my problem is resolved !

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `ids` should be unique, I replaced yours with `class`:

```
<div id="Tests">
    <div class="Test"> test 1</div>
    <div class="Test"> test 2</div>
</div>
```

Now add a listener to all elements with class `test`, and make that listener unselect any previously selected element, and select the current one.

**JS** solution

```
    var tests = document.getElementsByClassName('Test');
    for(var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
        tests[i].onclick = function() {
            var oldSelection = document.getElementsByClassName('selected')[0];
            if(oldSelection) oldSelection.className.replace('selected','');
            this.className += " selected";
        }
    }
```

**Jquery** solution:

```
$(document).on('click', '.Test', function(){
     $('.Test.selected').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

**Css** for class `selected`:

```
.selected{
     border:1px solid blue;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, my problem is resolved !